# Using virtualbox internal network with guest OS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, internal

I want to use virtualbox internal network with two Ubuntu guest OSes, but I can't connect to internal network. I tried do it with two Windows guest OSes it worked very well.

Comment: Better to post this on ServerFault or on the VirtualBox forums. Strictly speaking, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the firewall settings and make sure you have a bridge emulator installed (follow the instructions in [this blog post](http://samiux.wordpress.com/2007/07/11/bridge-network-interface-on-virtualbox/)).